# jQuery.mmenu conflict with other JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I've incorporated a Magento ecommerce site into our existing website and all is OK, but there are various different jQuerys and prototypes being used along the way.

I wanted to improve the site's mobile navigation and found the awesome jQuery.mmenu plugin.  I've integrated this into the site and it looks and mostly works great, but there are certain pages within the magento part of the site that have their js broken by the menu and as such the menu ceases to exist.

Looking at the code of a working page and non-working page I have found some differences in the js they use but I can't figure out how to rectify the issue:

Working page: http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/boots.html

Non-working page: http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/richa-monza-waterproof-leather-boots-black.html (notice that the menu doesn't show on the mobile size of the site and that the js tabs are broken as is the dropdown quick access, also the error message of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blocker' of undefined is shown in the console)

When comparing the code of the two pages and paying attention to the js used the following are included on the broken page but not on the working page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/js/varien/configurable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/js/infortis/jquery/plugins/jquery.cloudzoom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doble-shop.co.uk/shop/js/infortis/jquery/plugins/jquery.colorbox.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during jQuery initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.

If for some reason **two versions** of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling `$.noConflict( true );` from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

```
<script>
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Place this snippet right after including of the jQuery in your page.
Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the code already utilises:

`code`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

And this has enabled me to resolve some previous conflicts but not in this case, any further ideas? thanks

Comment: Use it like in the example, not `$j = ...`, but `$ = ...`

Comment: I have used $j so that I can reference the jQuery using the $j denotation whilst the $ notation remains for the prototype library.  I know that the non-conflict stuff is working fine as I can happily use $j for the jQuery work whilst the rest of the stuff works OK, until I get to a specific page.  Thanks